# importing html files into Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to import an external html file into Touch 2 and encountering errors. My view code is as follows:

```
Ext.define("GS.view.Demo", {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'container',

    requires: [
    'Ext.Component',
    'Ext.ItemCollection',
    'Ext.Mask',
    'Ext.behavior.Scrollable',
    'Ext.layout.Layout',
    ],

    config: {
    title: 'Demo',
    iconCls: 'star',


    items: [{
                flex: 1,
                margins: '0 2 0 0',
                title: 'Load raw html',
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                bodyPadding: 5,
                loader: {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    url: 'SHdemo.html'
                }
            }]

        }
    });
```

and apps.js:

```
//<debug>
 Ext.Loader.setPath({
'Ext': 'sdk/src'
});
//</debug>

Ext.application({
    controllers: ["Main"],

name: 'GS',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

views: ['Main', 'Home', 'Contact', 'Blog', 'Demo'],

icon: {
    57: 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
    72: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
    114: 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
    144: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
},

phoneStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen.jpg',
tabletStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen~ipad.jpg',

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('GS.view.Main'));
},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version.     Reload now?",
        function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
      );
    }
});
```

this code throws "The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'Ext.container.Container'"  and if I replace  'Ext.container.Container' with 'Ext.Container' in my view, I get "Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.demo". What's the proper procedure for importing external html files?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for xtype:'container'.
You should add an alias to your container like

```
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias:'widget.demo'
```

And adding it to the viewport could look like this

```
Ext.Viewport.add({xtype:'demo'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, fuzzy. the alias negates the widget error but I'm unsure where to declare the viewport code and as a result the external file doesn't load. I've just got an empty container on my "demo" screen.

Comment: You can add the xtype:'Demo' to the viewport and then call it with exampleviewport.setActiveItem(). Also container has no title config and margins should be margin, bodyPadding should just be padding. Instead of loader you should add something like initialize inside a listener. Above flex inside your Items config add xtype:'container' and change title to html.

Comment: The big issue here is the xtype : 'container' that you have. The xtype 'container' is already used by Ext.Container so you should give your class a unique xtype.

Past that like fuzzyLikeSheep mentions, you have many configs that aren't valid configs in this situation. An ajax call will help you instead of the loader config